# Where is /home/user located ? (/dev/sda1)

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have just install Ubuntu 18.04 via GCP but I would like to confirm where is located by `Home/User` folder.
How can I make sure it is on the `/dev/sda1`  where I have spave, please?

kind regards

Julie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the information you're looking for by launching the command `df -k`: this command shows you the relationship between devices, hard disk partitions, ... and the directories, located there.